# Web Scraping with BeautifulSoup and unchanging URL

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to **scrape** [this](http://classicalnumismaticgallery.com/advancesearch.aspx?auctioncode=0&pricerange=0&keyword=Indore&category=&material=0&lotno=&endlotno%27)

```
    r = requests.get(url) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text , 'lxml')
    details = soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'src'})
   details = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'product_contain'})
i=0
for d in details:
    print(i,d.get_text(strip=True).strip())
    i+=1
```

But it **scrapes** only one webpage. I inspected the `XHR` but nothing gets triggered when it changes the page.

I also inspected the `FORM DATA` in *advancesearch.aspx*, but it also doesn't have page index related information.
On page click event I found `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvItem$ctl01$ctl03` but not sure how to use this in URL.

What URL should I use to access the other pages?

Comment: What do you means? in your code you only request 1 url

Comment: Search results returns more than 25 items  . With this program we only get info which is present on first page.

Comment: There are POST requests made to http://classicalnumismaticgallery.com/advancesearch.aspx?auctioncode=0&pricerange=0&keyword=Indore&category=&material=0&lotno=&endlotno%27  and though you can remove lots of the headers and all the cookies, the rest of the post is pretty hefty and ugly (though perhaps it can be trimmed down)

Answer (score 2):

You should use Selenium in this case which will open the page in a browser and then you can handle the click event of navigator button and access the refreshed DOM each time. Here is a simple code for your reference:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.google.com")

browser.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").send_keys("book")
browser.find_element_by_name("btnK").click()
```

Comment: Note that you will need to download the "geckodriver" for running firefox through `selenium`. Make sure to also update your firefox before downloading the latest webdriver for firefox. Also, you can setup the path to where you keep the "geckodriver.exe" file, to be specified while instantiating `webdriver.Firefox()`. Once you get these things sorted out, the rest runs really smooth. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The page url you shared, shows that the page-numbers can be accessed through the following hyperlink-tags:

1. Current Page: `<a class="pager currentpage">`
2. Other Pages (each): `<a class="pager">`

You can access the relevant information as follows. The second line will give you a list of all the pages. Extract the `"href"` attribute from them. When you click on the button, a javascript fires and most likely appends a part of the url to open the new page.

```py
soup.findall('a', _class="pager currentpage")
soup.findall('a', _class="pager")
```

This is the text of one of the buttons. You will need to study the page source further to figure out what url is needed.

```html
<a class="pager currentpage"  
href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(
&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvItem$ctl01$ctl03&quot;, 
&quot;&quot;, 
true, &quot;&quot;, 
&quot;&quot;, false, true))" 
style="display:inline-block;width:27px;">1</a>
```

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

## A better Option

Use `selenium` browser automation to execute the clicks on such javascript-wrapped buttons.

Comment: I am keeping this response here for the time being. I will either update this with a better version or delete it.

Comment: Thanks. I will try with `Selenium`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve without `selenium`. Although code is not complete but we can **scrape** all the pages by looping `__EVENTTARGET`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests,json

def returnJson(wordmark):
    url = "https://classicalnumismaticgallery.com/advancesearch.aspx?auctioncode=0&pricerange=0&keyword=indore&category=&material=0&lotno=&endlotno="
    r_init = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r_init.text, 'html.parser')
    event_validation = soup.find("input", attrs={"name" : "__EVENTVALIDATION"})['value']
    view_state = soup.find("input", attrs={"name" : "__VIEWSTATE"})['value']

    pages=4
    event_target = 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvItem$ctl01$ctl{:>02d}'.format(pages)
    postdata = {
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DDLFilter' : '0',
        '__EVENTVALIDATION' : event_validation,
        '__EVENTTARGET' : event_target,
        "__VIEWSTATE" : view_state,
    }

    r = requests.post(url, data=postdata)
    return r

def scraping(r):
    description=''
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    desc = soup.find_all('div' , {'class' : 'product_contain'})
    for d in desc: 
         print(d)      


scraping(returnJson('indore'))
```

Comment: FYI it's __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrapping, 'Scrapping' means throwing things away like rubbish.